# Gaillardia seeds - when should they be emergening?

Tags: seeds

I bought some seeds, and planted them 2 weeks ago but still haven’t seen anything developing yet. Is this normal? Also, how often should I be watering these seedlings?

Some are in small plastic pots and others are in an egg carton with plastic coverings. (Very very novice gardener!)